Stripping symbols from a shared library used only by an apriori known set of executables
Is there any tooling that provides the functionality to strip unused symbols from shared object files given a set(>1) of ELF files that depend on this shared object file? My target is an embedded platform and I own/manage all the ELFs that will depend on this shared object when building the image. Since storage capacity is limited Im looking into removing unused code.
Im perfectly able to extract a set of undefined symbols that need to be provided by the SO (referenced by the set of libs/executables). But what I am specifically worried about is how to strip them and not accidently strip any symbols referenced by global symbols used by exectubles.

Even better than stripping symbols would be to strip out the symbols AND all "dead" code that won't be called, right? Do you own the process that builds the shared object file?

Yes. that would be better still and should be the goal indeed. I own the process that builds the shared object file, but I do not own the source. I can change link/compile flags but I cannot change the source code.


Is there any tooling that provides the functionality to strip unused symbols from shared object files

Not that I am aware of.

My target is an embedded platform and I own/manage all the ELFs that will depend on this shared object when building the image.

The best way to manage this is to

Compile all sources with -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections
Link all objects into a single binary and use -Wl,--icf=safe.

This will guarantee that only the used code is actually linked in, and will eliminate the (sometimes quite significant) overhead of using shared libraries.
Having a single binary also helps to save a lot of memory on the target, since (due to copy on write) all of the code and most of the data will be present in memory only once.
This is the "busybox" approach.
P.S.

I own the process that builds the shared object file, but I do not own the source.

If you own the build process, then you can do arbitrary transformations to the  source before you build it (i.e. copy and use sed to change the source in arbitrary ways), so you do in essence own the source as well.
